# Telegram replymarkup error

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I am trying to send notification to my channel but without reply_markup i could send but with markup, I couldnt. 
Hakre your answer didnt work.
Using urlencode i couldn`t send anything also.

```
$chefbotToken = "XXXXXXXXXX:AAHnUV8fk2gIp4_wudVcuyaxmuxsCPPMPwc";
$canallink= "@zehnuz";
$replyMarkup = array(
    'keyboard' => array(
        array("A", "B")
    )
);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);

$yangilik = $title.$shart;
$chef_bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$chefbotToken;
$url = $chef_bot_url."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$canallink."&text=".urlencode($yangilik)."&reply_markup=".urlencode($encodedMarkup);
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: If you construct an URL, you need to encode values appropriately. That is true for all parts of that URL and includes JSON encoded data which is not already URL encoded.

Comment: @hakre, the issue presented in this question is not the URL encoding. He tried to send a JSON over a GET URL, which is not a correct thing to do.
Also, he did not ask how to URL encode arrays in PHP, he asked for help identifying the problem.

Comment: There is no issue sending JSON (as any other string) over a GET URL. Especially as this is a small string. The problem in his code (at least one) is that he didn't encode an URL parameter properly - do you see a different Q&A resource that is in context here? If so, please share, there can be more than one reference Q&A linked.

Comment: $url = $chef_bot_url."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$canallink."&text=".urlencode($yangilik)."&reply_markup=".urlencode($encodedMarkup);
file_get_contents($url);

Comment: but it didnt work